# Problema programación en C básico

Tags: c, codeblocks

Estoy haciendo un programa en C en el que tengo que introducir un número real (de tipo float) correspondiéndose a la temperatura corporal de una persona. Si introduce una temperatura mayor o igual que 37 escribe este mensaje:

```
Fiebre: solicite atencion medica
```

En caso contrario, si se introduce una temperatura mayor que 0 y menor que 37. Debería mostrarse este mensaje:

```
Sin fiebre: es poco probable que este enfermo
```

El programa tiene que entrar en bucle si se introduce un valor menor o igual que 0.

Esto es hasta lo que he conseguido hacer, pero no veo qué error hay. ¿Podrían corregirme el fallo que hay en el código? Muchas gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float temp;
    do{
        printf("Introduzca su temperatura en Celsius:");
        scanf("&f",&temp);
        if(temp>0 && temp<37)
            printf("Sin fiebre: es poco probable que este enfermo");
        else
            {if(temp>=37)
            printf("Fiebre: solicite atencion medica");}}
    while(temp<=0);
    return 0;
}
```

El programa está realizado en CodeBlocks

Comment: porque decis que hay un error? que es lo que pasa?

Comment: Cómo han cambiado los ejercicios en clase con esta pandemia!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usas

```
scanf("&f", &temp);
```

para leer, pero el formato está equivocado y no lee nada.

La forma correcta es

```
scanf("%f", &temp);
```

Recuerda que en C/C++ todos los formatos empiezan con "%".

Answer (score 0):

El error esta al leer la variable temp
reemplaza scanf("&f",&temp); por scanf("%i",&temp);

Comment: Deberia ser `%f` en vez de `%i`..